# Failed to send SMS to Mobile Contact

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, mobileconnect, marketing-cloud-connect

It works fine when I import the contact manually.
But I can not send SMS to my test mobile phone(HK) when I use the Automation Import Mobile Contacts to a list. 
The Automation does two things:
  1. SQL query from Sync Data Extension(DE) to an ordinary DE.
  2. Import Mobile Contacts from the above DE to a contact list.
Can not send SMS using this list.
Can someone help me to troubleshoot it?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: How does it import? As in, what is the Status of the MobileConnect subscriber? Is the country code added? Is the number subscribed to a keyword?

Comment: I already said - 1. SQL query from Sync Data Extension(DE) to an ordinary DE. 2. Import Mobile Contacts from the above DE to a contact list.
The status of MobileConnect Contact is active, the country code is 'HK', the contact key is the PersonContactId.

Comment: And what about a keyword subscription?

Answer (score 0):

Under Mobile Connect Administration, for your sending number, ensure Hong Kong is selected as an enabled country.

I assume you are formatting your mobile number in correct format.

Are you sending SMS using a From Name? Or Short Code or Long Code?

If sending as a From Name then also ensure your from name is registered with local aggregators. Your account executive will be able to assist you with this